# Overlay raster RGB and polygon layer in leaflet/mapview with custom CRS in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I am trying to use R mapview/plainview or leaflet to display a raster RGB with a second layer that is a vector-based (spatial points or polygon) on top that I can toggle on an doff. It is important that both spatial layers are in polar stereographic (EPSG:3031) instead of having them reprojected to the standard EPSG:3857 web mercator projection used by leaflet. Also, I don't need to have any background tiles.

I can use planview to display a raster RGB without issue. The code is:

```
library(plainview)
plainview(poppendorf, r = 4, g = 3, b = 2)
```

However, it does not look like I can add a second-vector based layer to this. For example, I don't see a way to do something like:

```
plainview(poppendorf, r = 4, g = 3, b = 2) +
mapview(...)
```

Sticking directly with leaflet it seems I might be able to define a custom crs for 3031 [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html) but this would likely not work with raster based leaflet functions, like [addRasterRGB](https://rdrr.io/github/r-spatial/leafem/man/addRasterRGB.html).

So is there a way to code such a thing in R? Preferably with the plainview package?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with either plainview or mapview atm. I think it will never be available in plainview, but mapview might be able to display rasters with arbitrary crs soon(ish).

Comment: Thanks @TimSalabim for the quick response. Just to clarify - does the fact that I can't do this right now using mapview mean that it is also currently not possible to implement addRasterRGB with a custom crs directly using R leaflet and/or leaflet.extras?

Comment: I think it should be possible with plain leaflet.