# How to create an interactive map of stars/raster object with arbitrary crs?

Tags: r, leaflet, tmap, mapview, r-stars

### Problem

**I would like to create interactive maps of a regular grid that comes in a CRS which is not WGS84**. In my case the CRS is [EPSG:25833](https://epsg.io/25833) which has unit metres.

Given the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312434/overlay-raster-rgb-and-polygon-layer-in-leaflet-mapview-with-custom-crs-in-r), it does not seem to be possible to "display rasters with arbitrary crs".

Is this still the case? Or is there some kind of hack/solution now using packages like `plainview`, `leaflet`, `mapview` or `tmap` (or some other package I'm not aware of)?

Moreover, I do not understand what exactly `mapview::mapview` shows when I feed it a non-lat/lon stars object. See the following example, where I suppose that the `sf` object is rendered correctly whereas the `stars` object is not?

Would `tmap::tmap_leaflet` do a better job here?

### Example

```
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(stars)
library(tmap)

stars_obj <- raster(
  # Rough bbox of the city of Berlin, Germany
  xmn=360000, xmx=430000, 
  ymn=5790000, ymx=5850000,
  # CRS with units metres, NOT lat/lon
  crs = st_crs(25833)$wkt,
  # Grid cell size: 10km x 10km
  resolution = 10000) %>% 
  st_as_stars()
stars_obj <- stars_obj %>% 
  mutate(layer = 1:ncell(stars_obj))

sf_obj <- st_as_sf(stars_obj)

# mapview
mapview(stars_obj) + 
  mapview(sf_obj)

# tmap
tmap_leaflet(
  tm_shape(stars_obj) +
  tm_raster(alpha = 0.8)
)
```

This is how `mapview::mapview` renders it:
[image]

This is how `tmap::tmap_leaflet` renders it:
[image: tmap]

Comment: The rendering of the stars object seems correct. If you decrease the grid cell size to 1000 you will see that also the grid is being rotated and lines up with the sf object much better. As for your question about rasters with arbitrary crs, this is still not possible in any sensible way as far as I know.

Comment: I tried with a smaller resolution and indeed grid and sf align much better - I think I get now what the discrepancy is: Is it fair to say the max difference between the two is 1/2 of cell  width or height @TimSalabim ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The two are the same but for the raster we cannot rotate the whole thing so that for large cell sizes the difference between the two becomes more evident.